# Prove that the following application between $M_{n×n}(\Bbb R)$ and $M_{n^2×n^2}(\Bbb R)$ is an isometry such that $\det φ(X)≠ 0$ whether $\det X≠ 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, solution-verification, isometry

Let be $\varphi:M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)\rightarrow M_{n^2\times n^2}(\Bbb R)$ the application defined through the equation
$$
\varphi(X):=\sum_{i,j,h=1}^{n}x^{i,j}\hat e_{h+(i-1)n}\otimes\hat e_{j+(h-1)n}
$$
for any $X\in M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$.  So I ask me if $\varphi(X)$ is invertible when $X$ is and moreover observing that $\varphi$ is a linear application I ask also to me if $\varphi $ is an isometry. So first of all I suppose $n=3$ so that
$$
\varphi(X)=\begin{pmatrix}x_{1,1} && x_{1,2} && x_{1,3} && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0
\\0 && 0 && 0 && x_{1,1} && x_{1,2} && x_{1,3}  && 0 && 0 && 0 
\\0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && x_{1,1} && x_{1,2} && x_{1,3} 
\\x_{2,1} && x_{2,2} && x_{2,3} && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0
\\0 && 0 && 0 && x_{2,1} && x_{2,2} && x_{2,3}  && 0 && 0 && 0 
\\0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && x_{2,1} && x_{2,2} && x_{2,3}
\\x_{3,1} && x_{3,2} && x_{3,3} && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0
\\0 && 0 && 0 && x_{3,1} && x_{3,2} && x_{3,3}  && 0 && 0 && 0 
\\0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && x_{3,1} && x_{3,2} && x_{3,3}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
for any $X\in M_{3\times 3}(\Bbb R)$ and thus I observed that
$$
\varphi(X)\cdot\big(\varphi(Y^T)\big)^T=\begin{pmatrix}x_{1,1} && x_{1,2} && x_{1,3} && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0
\\0 && 0 && 0 && x_{1,1} && x_{1,2} && x_{1,3}  && 0 && 0 && 0 
\\0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && x_{1,1} && x_{1,2} && x_{1,3} 
\\x_{2,1} && x_{2,2} && x_{2,3} && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0
\\0 && 0 && 0 && x_{2,1} && x_{2,2} && x_{2,3}  && 0 && 0 && 0 
\\0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && x_{2,1} && x_{2,2} && x_{2,3}
\\x_{3,1} && x_{3,2} && x_{3,3} && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0
\\0 && 0 && 0 && x_{3,1} && x_{3,2} && x_{3,3}  && 0 && 0 && 0 
\\0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && x_{3,1} && x_{3,2} && x_{3,3}
\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}y_{1,1} && 0 && 0 && y_{1,2} && 0 && 0 && y_{1,3} && 0 && 0
\\y_{2,1} && 0 && 0 && y_{2,2} && 0 && 0  && y_{2,3} && 0 && 0 
\\y_{3,1} && 0 && 0 && y_{3,2} && 0 && 0 && y_{3,3} && 0 && 0 
\\0 && y_{1,1} && 0 && 0 && y_{1,2} && 0 && 0 && y_{1,3} && 0
\\0 && y_{1,2} && 0 && 0 && y_{2,2} && 0  && 0 && y_{2,3} && 0 
\\0 && y_{3,1} && 0 && 0 && y_{3,2} && 0 && 0 && y_{3,3} && 0
\\0 && 0 && y_{1,1} && 0 && 0 && y_{1,2} && 0 && 0 && y_{1,3}
\\0 && 0 && y_{2,1} && 0 && 0 && y_{2,2}  && 0 && 0 && y_{2,3} 
\\0 && 0 && y_{3,1} && 0 && 0 && y_{3,2} && 0 && 0 && y_{3,3}
\end{pmatrix}=\dots=\varphi(X\cdot Y^T)
$$
from which the statement follows observing that
$$
\text{rank}\,\varphi(I)=\text{rank}\,\begin{pmatrix}1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0
\\0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0  && 0 && 0 && 0 
\\0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0
\\0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0
\\0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0  && 0 && 0 && 0 
\\0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1 && 0
\\0 && 0 && 1 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0
\\0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1  && 0 && 0 && 0 
\\0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 0 && 1
\end{pmatrix}=9
$$
because this implies that
$$
\det\varphi(X)\cdot\det\varphi(X^{-T})=\det\big(\varphi(X)\cdot\varphi(X^{-T})\big)=\det\big(\varphi(X\cdot X^{-1})\big)=\det\big(\varphi(I)\big)\neq 0
$$
from which by the zero-product property I conclude that the quantity $\det\big(\varphi(X)\big)$ is not zero. Moreover observing that
$$
\text{tr}\big(\varphi(X)\big)=\text{tr}(X)
$$
for any $X\in M_{3\times 3}(\Bbb R)$ I conclude that
$$
\big\langle\varphi(X),\varphi(Y)\big\rangle=\text{tr}\big(\varphi(X)\cdot\varphi(Y)^T\big)=\\\text{tr}\Big(\varphi(X)\cdot\varphi\big((Y^T)^T\big)^T\Big)=\text{tr}\big(\varphi(X\cdot Y^T)\big)=\text{tr}\big(X\cdot Y^T\big)=\langle X,Y\rangle
$$
so that $\varphi$ is an isometry. So the statement is srely true for $n=3$, **provided that the argumetations I gave are correct**. Anyway I think that the statement, at least the first part, can be proved using the following conjecture which I did not able to prove

> > **CONJECTURE**
> >
> > Any isometry $\phi$ between $M_{n\times n}(\Bbb R)$ and $M_{n^2\times n^2}(\Bbb R)$ is such that
> > $$
> > \det\big(\phi(X)\big)\neq 0
> > $$
> > provided that $X$ is not singular.

Anyway I think that it is better to pose a dedicated question to this.

So I ask if the argumetation I gave are correct and if can be generalised to an arbitrary $n\in\Bbb N$. So could anyone help me, please?

Comment: Your conjecture is not correct. For example, consider the isometry for $n=2$ given by
$$
\phi \pmatrix{x_{11} & x_{12}\\ x_{21} & x_{22}} = 
\pmatrix{x_{11} & x_{12}&0&0\\ x_{21} & x_{22} &0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0}.
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann Okay, thanks for the counterexample. Anyway I have to point out that the expression of $\varphi$ for any arbitrary $n\in\Bbb N$ is a bad generalization of the expression of $\varphi$ for $n=3$. So can you say how write $\varphi$ for an arbitrary $n$? Then are my argumentation correct? Finally how implement it to the general case? Could you help me, please?

Comment: Forgive for the bother.

Comment: If we use $\otimes$ to denote the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product), we could write
$$
\varphi(X) = \pmatrix{X \otimes e_1 & X \otimes e_2 & \cdots & X \otimes e_n}
$$

Comment: You could express this a bit more nicely as a [Khatri Rao](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khatri%E2%80%93Rao_product) product

Comment: I edit the question: pheraps it seems I found the correct expression using tensor product. Anyway I did not encountered Khatri-Rao product but sometimes I encoutered the Kronecker product: the only one problem is that i did never study it in details but this could be the good excuse to study it. Only one question: is it different form the tensor product?

Comment: Clearly the are different because the tensor product works on linear map whereas the kroneker product works on matrices but I am curious to know if they are related.

Comment: The two interpretations of $\otimes$ correspond to competing interpretations of the tensor product. Your version (where the tensor product of two vectors is a matrix) corresponds to ["dyadics"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics) and the [classical treatment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor#Tensor_product) of a tensor product. The Kronecker product corresponds to the ["modern treatment"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_product#Tensor_product_of_linear_maps) of tensor products.

Comment: Okay, so probably I will study the kroneker product to update my formalism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the risk of being a bit confusing, I will use $\otimes$ to denote the [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product). We have
$$
\varphi(X) = \pmatrix{X \otimes e_1 & X \otimes e_2 & \cdots & X \otimes e_n}.
$$
From there, we find that
$$
\langle \varphi(X), \varphi(Y) \rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle X \otimes e_i, Y \otimes e_i\rangle = \sum_{i=1}^n \langle X,Y \rangle = n \langle X, Y \rangle.
$$
So, it is not true that $\varphi$ is an isometry. However, $\psi(X) := \varphi(X)/n$ **is** an isometry.

---

Regarding the comment: note that
$$
\varphi(X) \varphi(Y^T)^T = \\
\pmatrix{X \otimes e_1 & \cdots & X \otimes e_n} \pmatrix{Y \otimes e_1^T \\ \vdots \\ Y \otimes e_n^T} = \\
(X \otimes e_1)(Y \otimes e_1^T) + \cdots + (X \otimes e_n)(Y \otimes e_n^T) =\\
(XY) \otimes (e_1e_1^T) + \cdots + (XY) \otimes (e_ne_n^T) = \\
(XY) \otimes (e_1e_1^T + \cdots + e_ne_n^T) = \\
(XY) \otimes I.
$$
Note that in general, if $A$ is $m \times n$ with entries $a_{ij}$, then
$$
A \otimes I = \pmatrix{
a_{11} I & \cdots & a_{1n} I
\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots 
\\ a_{m1} I & \cdots & a_{mn} I}.
$$

Comment: Okay, so $\varphi$ is not an isometry: however at least is the equality $$\varphi(X)\cdot\big(\varphi(Y^T)\big)^T=\varphi(X\cdot Y^T)$$ true?

Comment: Anyway I think that it is false because if it was true then $\varphi$, at least for $n=3$, would be an isometry, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro See my latest edit

Comment: Okay, so $$\det\big(\varphi(X)\varphi(Y^T)^T\big)=\det\big((XY)\otimes I\big)=\Big(\det(XY)\Big)^n\cdot\big(\det I\big)^n=\big(\det(XY)\big)^n$$, right?

Comment: @AntonioMariaDiMauro That's correct

Comment: Okay, so this proves that $\det\varphi(X)$ is note zero, right?

Comment: @A Yes: for your map $\varphi$, if $\det(X)\neq 0$, then $\det(\varphi(X))$ will also be non-zero.

Comment: Okay, question approved. Thanks very much for the assistance!!!